# map through obj and dispatch key and state value

Tags: javascript

I'm having some trouble mapping through an obj of state and dispatching a returned string to the key name.

Expected output:
Key: cityMsg
newError: 'Please enter your city' or however it is validated

```
let {city} = this.state;
let addressInfo = { cityMsg: city};
for (const key of Object.keys(addressInfo)) {
    const newError = validateAddress[addressInfo[key]](addressInfo[key]);
    dispatch(updateErrors({ [key]: newError }))
}


export const validateAddress= {
    city: city => cityValidation(city),
  };

export const cityValidation = (e) => {
    if (e.trim() === '') {
      return 'Please enter your city';
    }
    return null;
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `validateAddress` has only one key which is `city`. Hence calling it like this `validateAddress[addressInfo[key]](addressInfo[key])` will produce an error unless `addressInfo[key]` is equal to string 'city'. I think this is what you're looking for actually:

```js
const validateAddress = {
    city: city => cityValidation(city),
  };

const cityValidation = (e) => {
    if (e.trim() === '') {
      return 'Please enter your city';
    }
    return null;
  };


let {city} = {city: ''};
let addressInfo = { cityMsg: city};
for (const key of Object.keys(addressInfo)) {
    const newError = validateAddress.city(addressInfo[key]);
    console.log({ [key]: newError })
}
```

To test, try updating the `let {city} = {city: ''};` part to any other city (e.g. Scottsdale) and run the code.

**EIDT:** Based on your comments, I think I also now understand the full context of what you're trying to achieve. You want to have multiple address values in the `validateAddress` address object. So here is how I would change your code:

```js
const validateAddress = {
    cityMsg: city => cityValidation(city),
     zipMsg: zip => zipValidation(zip),
  };

const cityValidation = (e) => {
    if (e.trim() === '') {
      return 'Please enter your city';
    }
    return null;
  };

  const zipValidation = (e) => {
    if (e.trim() === '') {
      return 'Please enter your Zip Code';
    }
    return null;
  };

let {city, zip} = {city: '', zip: ''};
let addressInfo = { cityMsg: city, zipMsg: zip};
for (const key of Object.keys(addressInfo)) {
    const newError = validateAddress[key](addressInfo[key]);
    console.log({ [key]: newError })
}
```

Note this part:

```
const validateAddress = {
    cityMsg: city => cityValidation(city),
     zipMsg: zip => zipValidation(zip),
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
export const cityValidation = (e) => {
    if (e.trim() === '') {
      return 'Please enter your city';
    }
    return null;
  };

let {city} = this.state;
let addressInfo = { cityMsg: city};
for (const key of Object.keys(addressInfo)) { 
    const newError = cityValidation(addressInfo[key]);
    dispatch(updateErrors({ [key]: newError }))
}
```

Comment: That works - but i will be having multiple address fields and want to put it all under the validate const.